# PHP namespaces - How to include third party libraries which are not in a namespace?

Tags: php, wordpress, oop, namespaces

I am using an autoloader which includes classes based on WordPress naming convention, meaning, `My_Class` should reside in `class-my-class.php`. It works fine. However, I have to use a third party library, which is differently named and doesn't use a namespace. How would I use it in my code? Do I need to include it explicitly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `\` before the beginning of a class represents the global namespace.

> my.class.php

```
<?php

class myClass {

}

?>
```

> index.php

```
<?php

require( 'my.class.php' );

$obj = new \myClass;

var_dump( $obj );

?>
```

Anyway, if you want to autoload a class without namespace, you can use the following trick in your autoloader:

```
if ( file_exists( $filepath = str_replace( '\\', '/', $class ) ) { 
     require $filepath;
}

$obj = \myClass;
```

Comment: Thanks! So I have to require the library's file explicitly?

Comment: Thanks again, I required the file in the bootstrap file where I initiate the autoloader and used the class with the global namespace.